# raggedright caption option not working in beamer

Tags: beamer, captions

I'm trying to right-align one my captions in `beamer`. For that I use the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.4\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}[justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=off]%
     {This is a long caption just to reach the second line}
\column{0.6\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, this is not working and I wonder if this is due to `beamer`or if I'm doing something wrong. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the caption package with `compatibility=false` and to use `\captionsetup` to specify your options, otherwise they will not have any effect.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.4\textwidth}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedleft}
\captionof{figure}{This is a long caption just to reach the second line}
\column{0.6\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks. I guess, I'll just ignore the warning "But please note that using this option is neither recommended nor supported since unwanted side-effects or even errors could occur afterwards. (For that reason you will get a warning about this." in the `caption`package documentation, as there seem to be no ill effects in my case.

Comment: @PacificOrion Yes, unfortunately there is no other way (that I know) to let `beamer` and `caption` work together. An alternative could be to get rid of `caption` completely and use `beamer` native facilities for captions. Let me know if you want me to make an example of a `beamer` native caption.